# Import error while customizing django-comments-xtd

Tags: python, django, importerror, django-settings, django-comments

acordign to the documentation for django-XtdComments in order to have my custom comment model instead of XtdComment the setting file should be like this:

COMMENTS_APP = "django_comments_xtd"

COMMENTS_XTD_MODEL = 'commenting.models.BookComment'

at this poin I have a commenting app and a BookComment model to use for Comment model but setting file gives me Import Error that Module "commenting.models" does not define a "BookComment" attribute/class
can anyone help me what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I got this error was circular import in models.py
It solved by deleting useless imports